# Using alternative MVC framework

Tags: open-source, asp.net, frameworks, mvc, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and EF. I read about open source implementations of MVC pattern like Spring, FubuMVC, Castle etc.

I want to know how flexible these alternatives are when compared with ASP.NET MVC. Which one is widely used and whose help is easily available on the NET?

Comment: Question looks too broad. MVC is a paradigm; there is numerous implementations of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to use an open source alternative .NET "framework" I would recommend [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy)

Nancy has a significant amount of community activity and if you look at the commit history you see it's actively being worked on.

It's a significantly more lightweight web framework that's similar to Ruby's [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). This means you can use it to handle the basic web things you need

- Routing
- Views
- Interaction with HTTP servers

> The goal of the framework is to stay out of the way as much as possible and provide a super-duper-happy-path to all interactions.

It's a lightweight cross platform framework that does the minimal amount you need, doesn't dictate anything about the application architecture you should be using and then just get's out of your way.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any restriction on using Asp.net MVC. You have full rights to use it and abuse it just like Spring or Castle.

The most widely used is Asp.net MVC only because it comes from the desk of Microsoft itself and has great amount of documentation and tutorials at [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).

If you are starting with Asp.net MVC, I would suggest you to go with it and then try out the other frameworks later

Comment: +1 for `You have full rights to use it and abuse` - So true...